# Is there a way to exclude posts based on meta_values?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a need to exclude posts based on a custom field type. It will probably be a field such as "legacy" or "depricated". I searched for an example on how this would be done but I haven't found anything worth while. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
            $software = array('post_type' => 'software', 'category_name' => $model);
            query_posts( $software );
            get_template_part( 'loop', 'software' );
            wp_reset_query();
            ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met the same problem before. I tried to use `meta_query` parameter in the query argument, but didn't succeed. The code I tried to use looks like this:

```
$software = array(
    'post_type' => 'software',
    'meta_query' => array('key' => 'legacy', 'value' => 1, 'compare' => '!=')
);
query_posts($software);
```

But the problem is this query also excludes posts that don't have that meta key.

So I had to use a custom query, that gets all posts with `legacy` meta key, and then excludes them:

```
global $wpdb;
$legacy = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='legacy'");

$software = array(
    'post_type' => 'software',
    'post__not_in' => $legacy
);
query_posts($software);
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Appreciate the help! I seem to be seeing the same posts. I'm confused how post__not_in works with custom fields? Does it understand when a key is on or off using a checkbox?

Comment: The `post__not_in` only refers to an array of post IDs, which is `$legacy` in the example. The query that get `$legacy` only check if the meta key is set or not (but you can change it to check the meta value as well).

Comment: Instead of custom query for IDs you can do usual `get_posts()` and add `'fields' => 'ids'` to arguments. Highly useful recent addition, not known/documented much yet. :)

Comment: @Rarst: Nice point. I avoided to use `get_posts()` as I thought it would do a "big" query. Haven't known about the `fields` parameter. Thanks :)